# How can I create a CSS Selector to select the content of a td using the content of a th?

Tags: css, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

I'm writing a crawler using scrapy and by using the following python line I managed to get the data I'm looking for:

Python line:

```
response.css("article.college div.span8.profile > table > tbody > tr").extract()
```

It returns me the following result:

```
['<tr>\n<th>Institution Name:</th>\n<td>Harvard University</td>\n</tr>',
 '<tr>\n<th>Administration</th>\n<td>Private</td>\n</tr>',
 '<tr>\n<th>State</th>\n<td>\nMassachussets\t\n</td>\n</tr>']
```

However, I'd like to access the attribute value indexing by the attribute name. I wanna do something like this:

```
response.css(<magic containing 'Institution Name'>)
```

And be able to retrieve the correspondent value, in this case, this:

```
\n<td>Harvard University</td>\n
```

Can someone help me how to figure this out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use XPath:

```
response.xpath('//tr[th="Institution Name:"]/td/text()').extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm modifying your extractor as xpath :

```
response.xpath("//table//tbody//tr[contains(., 'Institution Name')]/td/text()").extract()
```

I just added that any `tr` containing `Institution Name` text (case sensitive) then pick `td` of that `tr`

Answer (score 0):

In this situations I use list comprehensions like this one

```
institution_name = [line.css("td").extract_first() for line in response.css("article.college div.span8.profile > table > tbody > tr") if "Institution Name" in line.extract()]
```